# Does making reference variable volatile, make all its field volatile too in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I have read that making reference variable volatile, does not make  its inner fields volatile.But i tried with below example where it looks like volatile nature is applied to inner fields of class as well.

User.java:-
// user class having field "flag" set as true.

```
public class User {

    private boolean flag=true;

    public boolean isFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

MyRunnableThread1.java:-

here i have made "user" as volatile and not its inner field "flag" as volatile

child thread is continuously in loop at "while(this.user.isFlag())".

```
public class MyRunnableThread1 implements Runnable {

    private String threadName;
    private  volatile User  user; 

    public MyRunnableThread1(String threadName,User user)
    {
        this.threadName=threadName; 
        this.user=user;
    } 

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("child thread:"+threadName+" started");

        while(this.user.isFlag()) {

        }
        System.out.println("child thread:"+threadName+" finished");
    }
}
```

ThreadDemo.java:-

in main thread we sets the value of field "flag" of "User" object as false
to terminate the loop in child thread

```
public class ThreadDemo {

    public static void main(final String[] arguments) throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("main thread started");

        User user=new User(); 
        MyRunnableThread1 myRunnableThread1=new MyRunnableThread1("Thread1",user);
        Thread t=new Thread(myRunnableThread1);
        t.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception in sleep:"+e);
        }

        myRunnableThread1.getUser().setFlag(false);

        System.out.println("main thread finished"); 
    }
}
```

o/p:-

main thread started
child thread:Thread1 started
main thread finished
child thread:Thread1 finished

In above example I have made "user" variable as volatile in "MyRunnableThread1.java" class.
User object has field "flag" which is true at time of instantiation.
After starting the child thread where it continuously execute the loop , the main thread changes the value of field "flag" of user object to false.
But here field "flag" is not volatile instead the "user" reference variable is volatile.But still here  the change in value of field "flag" in main thread is reflected in child thread.It behaves as if field "flag" is also volatile.
can anyone help with above issue??

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html#full-volatile-visibility-guarantee

Comment: Also [Java Tutoials: Atomic Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html)

Comment: just FYI, it's _really_ hard to see the effects of incorrect synchronization in test/debug code, for all kinds of reasons.  which is why you typically don't see these errors in your dev setup, only when you go to production and _really_ stress things.

Comment: A variable does not have fields.  The value of the `user` variable in your example is only a _reference_ to a `User` object.  The `User` object itself is stored on the heap, not in the variable.

Comment: Any variable in Java is allowed to behave as if it were volatile even if not declared so. There is no guarantee that its value is cached locally in each thread.

Answer (score 4):

From JLS:

> 8.3.1.4. volatile Fields
>
> The Java programming language allows threads to access shared
>   variables (§17.1). As a rule, to ensure that shared variables are
>   consistently and reliably updated, a thread should ensure that it has
>   exclusive use of such variables by obtaining a lock that,
>   conventionally, enforces mutual exclusion for those shared variables.
>
> The Java programming language provides a second mechanism, volatile
>   fields, that is more convenient than locking for some purposes.
>
> A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java Memory Model
>   ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable
>   (§17.4).

But objects are not variables. Then in your case what is consistent is the value of `user` which means that all threads see the same reference, not that they observe the same values for its inner content.

Answer (score 0):

You're always accessing the members through the reference to the instance:

`this.user.isFlag()`

This way, your loop contains a read of a volatile variable `user` and the loop's body is not optimized out.

Try getting the instance reference to a local variable before the loop, and you'll see the difference.

E.g.:

```
    User u = this.user;
    while(u.isFlag())
    {

    }
```

Comment: that doesn't technically make a difference, although it may increase the chances of seeing the problem

Comment: Yes it does. `this.user.isFlag()` gives us a volatile read inside the loop. Therefore the loop cannot be optimized out. `u.isFlag()` is, according to Java memory model, a no-op. The flag is not volatile, so cannot change in a tight loop.

Comment: A `volatile` read prevents the loop optimization, but it does not, by itself, guarantee that the thread will see the most recent version of whatever `isFlag()` returns.  The language only guarantees that if thread A reads some volatile variable, then it will be able to see whatever thread B wrote to memory _before thread B updated_ the same volatile variable.

Comment: @jameslarge That is correct.  All we're guaranteeing is that `user.flag` will be read every iteration of the loop. A very strict implementation of java MM would prevent the changes in `flag` from being seen by other threads. In fat, if you have a tight loop setting flag, and wait for optimization, that's exactly what will happen. However, in this case, we only set the flag once. All CPUs guarantee that all threads *eventually* see data set by other threads, in no particular order and in no specific time. So the repeated read and a single set causes this thing to work.

Comment: basically what @jameslarge said.  i'm not sure where you get that the flag cannot change in a tight loop.  nothing about the MM says that it _can't_ change, only that it is not _required_ to change.

Comment: @jtahlborn The closest thing I can cite in support of my position is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.9 . The way I understand it is that any stretch of code that does not have anything that is guaranteed to make stuff from other threads visible (e.g. reading of a volatile or entering a synchronized or calling join()) should be treated as a single-threaded code. And if such single-threaded code boils down to an infinite loop, the JIT is free to optimize it as such. Hence "cannot change".

Comment: *We also define a special hang action. If behavior is described by a set of external actions including a hang action, it indicates a behavior where after the external actions are observed, the program can run for an unbounded amount of time without performing any additional external actions or terminating. Programs can hang if all threads are blocked or if the program can perform an unbounded number of actions without performing any external actions.*

Comment: i think your own comments make my point.  you use the words "allowable" and "is free to".  i.e. either way is a valid execution.  if it is "allowable" to optimize the loop, that means the jvm _does not have to_ optimize the loop.  hence, you could still get new values each time through.

Comment: @jtahlborn Very true, JIT does not have to optimize the check away. In the actual Java 1.8 Hot Spot implementation it does. Please try changing the flag after the loop had been going for a couple seconds and see what happens. In any case, I think at this point we do understand each other :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not assume that declaring a reference volatile guarantees safe publication of the members of the referenced object.

When the referent is mutable and lacks thread safety, other threads might see a partially constructed object or an object in a inconsistent state.

When the referent is immutable, declaring the reference `volatile` suffices to guarantee safe publication of the members of the referent. You cannot use the `volatile` to guarantee safe publication of mutable objects. Use of the `volatile` can only guarantee safe publication of primitive fields, object references, or fields of immutable object referents.

You can use volatile variables instead of locks only under a restricted set of circumstances. Both of the following criteria must be met for volatile variables to provide the desired thread-safety:

- Writes to the variable do not depend on its current value.
- The variable does not participate in invariants with other variables.

Summary:

`User` is mutable, one `Thread` setting the `flag` value does not guarantees that the new value will be visible to another `Thread`.

**Option 1:** use `volatile flag`:

```
public class User {
    private volatile boolean flag = true;
}
```

**Option 2:** use `AtomicBoolean`:

```
public class User {
    private final AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    public boolean isFlag() {
        return flag.get();
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag.set(flag);
    }
}
```

**Option 3:** use `synchronized`:

```
public class User {
    private boolean flag = true;

    public synchronized boolean isFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public synchronized void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is using a `Boolean` object with a boxing setter an option?
E.g. `field: private final Boolean flag = new Boolean(true);` and `setter: this.flag = new Boolean(flag)`

Comment: You cannot assign a new value to the `final` field once it was instantiated. Anyway setter and getter should be `synchronized` to avoid race conditions and visibility problems.

Comment: Sorry, I've overseen the `final` keyword. I understand the visibility problems - but wouldn't these be atomic operations and thus thread-safe, avoiding race conditions at least?

Comment: First of all "a class is thread-safe when it continues to behave correctly when accessed from multiple threads" and "possibility of incorrect results in the presence of unlucky timing called race condition" (quotes from "Java Concurrency in Practice"). Assignment of a reference is an atomic operation by itself, but visibility problems lead to data races and race conditions what leads to unpredictable behaviour of the code. Such code definitely cannot be called thread safe.